# Problemas ao comparar objetos vindo de uma list

Tags: java

Estou tentando comparar um objeto vindo de uma lista antes de inserir no banco só que me retorna o endereço do objeto.

Segue o código.

Método da class DAO

```
public List<ServicoVO> verificaNome(ServicoVO servico) throws SQLException{

        String sql = ("SELECT nome_servico FROM servico  where nome_servico like '%" + servico.getNome_servico() + "%'");
        List<ServicoVO> servicos = new ArrayList<ServicoVO>();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            servico.setNome_servico(rs.getString("nome_servico"));
            servicos.add(servico);
        }
        return servicos;

    }
```

Métodos da class BO

Aqui eu comparo se o nome esta igual ao da lista , caso não estiver igual insere,caso estiver não insere.

```
public void incluirServico(ServicoVO ServicoVO) throws SQLException {


        ServicoDAO dao = new ServicoDAO();
        if(verificaServico(ServicoVO).equals(ServicoVO.getNome_servico())){
            System.out.println("Valores iguais , item não cadastrado");
        }else{
            dao.incluirServico(ServicoVO);
        }

    }
```

Aqui retorna uma lista de servico

```
public List<ServicoVO> verificaServico(ServicoVO Servico) throws SQLException {

        List<ServicoVO> servico = new ServicoDAO().verificaNome(Servico);

        return servico;
    }
```

Class ServicoVO

```
public String getNome_servico() {
        return nome_servico;
    }
    public void setNome_servico(String nome_servico) {
        this.nome_servico = nome_servico;
    }
```

Como eu poderia comparar o resultado do método verificaServico sem que me traga
o endereço do objeto no metodo `incluirServico`.

Comment: "`if(verificaServico(ServicoVO).equals(ServicoVO.getNome_servico())`" é uma verificação, ela não ficaria melhor dentro de `verificarServico(...)`? Aí você poderia fazer `verificarServico(...)` retornar um `boolean` que eu acho que faz muito mais sentido para um método que verifica algo (ou ainda, o método de verificação poderia lançar uma Exception, dependendo do caso).

Comment: Poste o código do método `getNome_servico()`, por favor.

Comment: Obg pela resposta. Pelo código do colega abaixo eu consigo verificar , mas tem outro problema quando os serviços não são iguais ele não entra no for..ai não sei o que esta acontecendo.Postei o código que vc me pediu tmb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

```
public boolean incluirServico(ServicoVO servicoVO) throws SQLException {


    ServicoDAO dao = new ServicoDAO();

        System.out.println(verificaServico(servicoVO));
        if(verificaServico(servicoVO)){
        System.out.println("Inserido");
        dao.incluirServico(servicoVO);
        return true;
        }
        return false;


}

public boolean verificaServico(ServicoVO servicoVO) throws SQLException {

    List<ServicoVO> servico = new ServicoDAO().verificaNome(servicoVO);
    for (ServicoVO ser : servico) {
     if(ser.getNome_servico().equals(servicoVO.getNome_servico()));
    return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Com o método booleam ficou fácil de resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei o que seu `getNome_servico()` retorna mas imagino que não seja uma coleção. De qualquer forma, o seu método `verificaServico()` está retornando uma `List`, dessa forma você deveria iterar (percorrer) essa lista e comparar o valor de um atributo (imagino que o nome), algo mais ou menos assim:

```
ServicoDAO dao = new ServicoDAO();

for (ServicoVO servico : verificaServico(ServicoVO)) 
{
   if(servico.getNome_servico().equals(ServicoVO.getNome_servico())){
       System.out.println("Valores iguais , item não cadastrado");
   }else{
       dao.incluirServico(ServicoVO);
   }
}
```

Outro ponto importante que você deve alterar é iniciar parâmetros sempre em letra minúscula. A passagem de parâmetro nos métodos `incluirServico()` e `verificaServico()` está iniciando em letra maiúscula.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta.Agora ele esta comparando , mas quando o valores são diferentes ele nem entra no for e não consigo inserir.Fiz uns testes colocando sysout antes do if e nem mostra no console.

Comment: O bloco de código dentro do for vai ser alcançado apenas se a coleção retornada no método `verificaServico()` possuir ao menos um valor. O que provavelmente está acontecendo no seu caso é que a coleção retornada não possui valor. Já que você está debugando usando sysout, coloca um antes do bloco do `for` para verificar o retorno do método.

Comment: Obg pela ajuda resolvi a um tempo atrás só que esqueci de posta com a correria .